# Index not listed in TOC and no hyperlinks in Index after tex4ebook conversion

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

The MWE below creates and index with hyperlinks on pages in the generated PDF. The index also appears in the TOC. However, the epub generated with `tex4ebook` looks great and the index appears. However, the index is not listed in my TOC and its pages are not hyperlinked.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{The First Chapter}
Here is some text.\index{text}
\chapter{The Second Chapter}
Here is some text.\index{text}


\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Here's the PDF:
[image]

Here's the EPUB:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX4ht doesn't support Memoir's indexing system yet, here is a fix for that, `memoir.4ht`:

```
% memoir.4ht (2021-01-29-14:14), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2003-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2021 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2021-01-29-14:14}

\input book.4ht
\input verse.4ht
\input booktabs.4ht
\let\columnlines\empty

\let\rm\empty
\let\sf\empty
\let\tt\empty
\let\bf\empty
\let\it\empty

\renewcommand*{\@memoldfonterr}[3]{}
\renewcommand*{\@memoldfontwarn}[3]{}


\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
   \gHAdvance\:mpNum by 1
\HAssign\minipageNum=\:mpNum \relax
%
   {\SkipRefstepAnchor \let\addcontentsline\:gobbleIII\no@chapter[#1]{}%
    \global\let\f@rtoc\f@rtoc
    \ifx\f@rtoc\empty\gdef\f@rtoc{#2}\fi
    \global\let\f@rhdr\f@rhdr  }%
   \HtmlEnv   \Toc:Title{\f@rtoc}\:chapter{#2}}
\def\:tempc{\@ifstar\o:tableofcontents:\o:tableofcontents:}
\HLet\tableofcontents\:tempc
\Def:Section\book{\thebook}{#1}
\NewConfigure{abstracttitle}{2}
\newenvironment{abstracttitle4ht}{\a:abstracttitle}{\b:abstracttitle\par\noindent}
% get rid of all extra <span> elements introduced by smaller font size
% \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont}
% \renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont}
% use our dummy environment to insert tags around the abstract title
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{abstracttitle4ht}

\NewConfigure{poemline}{2}
\NewConfigure{legend}{2}
\renewcommand\legend[1]{\a:legend #1\b:legend}
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
\ifHy@hyperfootnotes
\Hy@hyperfootnotesfalse
\newcounter{Hfootnote}
\fi
}{}

\ifx \memgobble\:UnDef
   \pend:defI\getthelinenumber{%
   \let\sv:thepoemline\thepoemline
   \pend:def\thepoemline{\a:poemline}%
   \append:def\thepoemline{\b:poemline}}
\append:defI\getthelinenumber{\let\thepoemline\sv:thepoemline}

\else
   \pend:defII\getthelinenumber{%
   \let\sv:thepoemline\thepoemline
   \pend:def\thepoemline{\a:poemline}%
   \append:def\thepoemline{\b:poemline}}
\append:defII\getthelinenumber{\let\thepoemline\sv:thepoemline}

   \let\no@Msect\M@sect
\NewConfigure{@sec @ssect}[1]{%
   \def\rdef:sec##1{#1\csname no@##1\endcsname}}
\:CheckOption{sections-}     \if:Option
   \Configure{@sec @ssect}{}
\else
   \Configure{@sec @ssect}{%
      \let\sv:Sc\:Sc \let\sv:sect\@sect \let\sv:ssect\@ssect
\let\sv:Msect\M@sect
\let\:Sc\:gobble
      \def\M@sect##1##2##3##4##5##6[##7][##8]##9{%
   \ifx \o:@seccntformat:\:UnDef
  \let\o:@seccntformat:\@seccntformat
\fi
\let\@seccntformat\:gobble
%
   \let\M@sect\no@Msect   \xdef\c:secnumdepth{##2}%
   {\SkipRefstepAnchor \let\addcontentsline\:gobbleIII \let\mark\:gobble
    \no@Msect{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}[{##7}][{##8}]{}}%
   \let\:Sc\sv:Sc \let\@sect\sv:sect \let\@ssect\sv:ssect
\let\M@sect\sv:Msect
%
   \let\@seccntformat=\o:@seccntformat:
%
   \HtmlEnv    \Toc:Title{##8}\csname no:#1\endcsname{##9}}%
%
      \def\@sect##1##2##3##4##5##6[##7]##8{%
   \ifx \o:@seccntformat:\:UnDef
  \let\o:@seccntformat:\@seccntformat
\fi
\let\@seccntformat\:gobble
%
   \let\@sect\no@sect   \xdef\c:secnumdepth{##2}%
   {\SkipRefstepAnchor \let\addcontentsline\:gobbleIII \let\mark\:gobble
    \no@sect{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}[{##7}]{}}%
   \let\:Sc\sv:Sc \let\@sect\sv:sect \let\@ssect\sv:ssect
\let\M@sect\sv:Msect
%
   \let\@seccntformat=\o:@seccntformat:
%
   \HtmlEnv    \Toc:Title{##7}\csname no:#1\endcsname{##8}}%
%
      \def\@ssect##1##2##3##4##5{%
   \gdef\ssect:ttl{##5}%
%
   \let\@ssect\no@ssect
   {\def\addcontentsline####1####2####3{}%
    \no@ssect{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}{}}%
   \let\:Sc\sv:Sc \let\@sect\sv:sect \let\@ssect\sv:ssect
\let\M@sect\sv:Msect
%
   \HtmlEnv   \csname :like#1\endcsname{##5}}%
\IgnorePar}
\fi

\fi

\def\:tempa#1|#2|#3\\{%
\html:addr\hbox{\Link-{}{dx\last:haddr}\EndLink}%
\expandafter\protected@write\csname \jobname @idxfile\endcsname{}{\string\beforeentry{\RefFileNumber\FileNumber}{dx\last:haddr}{}}%
\expandafter\protected@write\csname \jobname @idxfile\endcsname{}{\string\indexentry[\@idxfile]{#1}{\thepage}}%
\endgroup%
\@esphack%
}
\HLet\@@wrindexhyp\:tempa
\HLet\@@wrspindexhyp\:tempa

% we use make4ht's splitindex functionality, which produces .ind files in the form of \jobname-idxname.ind
\renewcommand{\printindex}[1][\jobname]{\@input@{\jobname-#1.ind}}

\Hinput{memoir}
\endinput
```

The important part is this:

```
\def\:tempa#1|#2|#3\\{%
\html:addr\hbox{\Link-{}{dx\last:haddr}\EndLink}%
\expandafter\protected@write\csname \jobname @idxfile\endcsname{}{\string\beforeentry{\RefFileNumber\FileNumber}{dx\last:haddr}{}}%
\expandafter\protected@write\csname \jobname @idxfile\endcsname{}{\string\indexentry[\@idxfile]{#1}{\thepage}}%
\endgroup%
\@esphack%
}
\HLet\@@wrindexhyp\:tempa
\HLet\@@wrspindexhyp\:tempa

% we use make4ht's splitindex functionality, which produces .ind files in the form of \jobname-idxname.ind
\renewcommand{\printindex}[1][\jobname]{\@input@{\jobname-#1.ind}}
```

It redefines the command used for writing index info to the auxiliary file, inserts hyperlink destination, which is necessary to be able to link back to the text from the index, and writes index entry in the format needed by `make4ht`.

The indexing is not supported out of the box, you need to [explicitly call indexing commands](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#indexing) in a build file. For example, you can save the following code as `build.lua`:

```lua
Make:htlatex {} 
Make:makeindex {} 
Make:htlatex{}
```

The last thing is to include the index in TOC. You can try this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\RenewDocumentCommand\tableofcontents{s}{\TableOfContents[part,likepart,chapter,likechapter,section,likesection,subsection,likesubsection]}
\EndPreamble
```

It redefines `\tableofcontents` command to print also starred version of sectioning commands (thanks to `likechapter` etc.).

Compile using:

```
$ tex4ebook -c config.cfg -e build.lua sample.tex
```

This is the resulting TOC:

[image]

And the index:

[image]

Links should point to the correct point in the text.